# Trouble looping through XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a need to loop through XML, create a new element with values from existing elements, and then delete the existing elements.  I've made it pretty far and it works as expected for the first loop, but certain parts fail on subsequent loops.  Hoping someone can take a look and provide some direction as I've exhausted my slim knowledge of PowerShell.  Here's an example of the beginning XML.  Note that the  element might not be nested consistently:

```
<val:root xmlns:val="urn:dummy">
  <bla>foo</bla>
  <value>
    <sometag>foo</sometag>
    <displayx>1x</displayx>
    <displayy>1y</displayy>
    <displaywidth>1w</displaywidth>
    <displayheight>1h</displayheight>
    <someothertag>foo</someothertag>
  </value>
  <value>
    <sometag>foo</sometag>
    <displayx>2x</displayx>
    <displayy>2y</displayy>
    <someothertag>foo</someothertag>
    <yetanothertag>foo</yetanothertag>
  </value>
  <nest>
      <value>
        <displayx>3x</displayx>
        <displayy>3y</displayy>
        <displaywidth>3w</displaywidth>
        <displayheight>3h</displayheight>
        <someothertag>foo</someothertag>
      </value>
  </nest>
</val:root>
```

When run, here's the output:

```
<val:root xmlns:val="urn:dummy">
  <bla>foo</bla>
  <value>
    <sometag>foo</sometag>
    <someothertag>foo</someothertag>
    <display x="1x" y="1y" w="1w" h="1h" />
  </value>
  <value>
    <sometag>foo</sometag>
    <someothertag>foo</someothertag>
    <yetanothertag>foo</yetanothertag>
    <display x="" y="" />
  </value>
  <nest>
    <value>
      <someothertag>foo</someothertag>
    </value>
  </nest>
</val:root>
```

The first  node is perfect.  The values of existing display elements were added to a new  element as attributes.  Subsequent value elements are not capturing values, and the 3rd (a nested one) doesn't even have the new element created.

Here's is the current script:

```
# Define the document
$filename = "2.xml";

# Read Content
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content (Resolve-Path $fileName));

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("*/value")
#$nodes = $xml.root.value

# Loop through each <value> element, capture <display*> values, write values to new element as attributes
foreach ($v in $nodes) {
    # Create new element
    $newDisplay = $v.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("display"));
    # Collect existing x value and write as attribute
    $x = $v.displayx
    $newDisplay.SetAttribute("x","$x");
    # Collect existing y value and write as attribute
    $y = $v.displayy
    $newDisplay.SetAttribute("y","$y");
    # Collect existing w value, if available, and write as attribute
    $w = $v.displaywidth
    if($v.displaywidth -ne $null) {
        $newDisplay.SetAttribute("w","$w");
        }
    # Collect existing w value, if available, and write as attribute
    $h = $v.displayheight
    if($v.displayheight -ne $null) {
        $newDisplay.SetAttribute("h","$h");
        }

    # Delete old elements
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displayx")
    while ($node -ne $null)
    {
        $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
        $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displayx")
    }
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displayy")
    while ($node -ne $null)
    {
        $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
        $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displayy")
    }
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displaywidth")
    while ($node -ne $null)
    {
        $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
        $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displaywidth")
    }
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displayheight")
    while ($node -ne $null)
    {
        $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
        $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//displayheight")
    }
} 

# Save
$xml.Save((Resolve-Path $filename));
```

The width and height elements are optional, hence the if statements for those.

Obviously something to do with how it's collecting information and looping, but this is where I could use some help.  I'm sure the way I'm removing nodes could be cleaner as well...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because all old elements have been deleted in the first time of foreach loop.
Removing only the child elements of `$v` solves this problem.

```
$filename = "2.xml"

$doc = [xml](Get-Content $filename)

# get all value elements
$values = $doc.SelectNodes("//value")

foreach ($v in $values) {

    # create and append new element
    $newDisplay = $v.AppendChild($doc.CreateElement("display"))

    # get old elements
    $x, $y, $w, $h = $v["displayx", "displayy", "displaywidth", "displayheight"]

    # set attributes of new element
    $newDisplay.SetAttribute("x", $x.InnerText)
    $newDisplay.SetAttribute("y", $y.InnerText)
    if ($w -and $h) {
        $newDisplay.SetAttribute("w", $w.InnerText)
        $newDisplay.SetAttribute("h", $h.InnerText)
    }

    # delete old elements
    @($x, $y, $w, $h) -ne $null | foreach { [void]$v.RemoveChild($_) }
}

$doc.Save("$pwd/result.xml");
```

Comment: Belated thanks for the info provided above.  Worked perfectly and make sense.